# how to map fn to ctrl with ubuntu on a macbook pro

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, keyboard, fn-key

I want both the fn key and the ctrl key to act like a control key in Ubuntu on my MBP, just like I was able to do with Karabiner under macOS.  I first tried xmodmap, but xev doesn't return any event for the Fn key.  I then found hid_apple which allows me to swap them and I tried hacking the code to make both return KEY_LEFTCTRL, but it didn't seem to have the effect I wanted.  I can swap them, but one of them is always a "dead key" (e.g. the Fn key and returns no event to xev).

If it makes a difference, what I really care about is how they work in Emacs26 with a "DISPLAY" so that it is using X.

Comment: Does this solve your issue @intel_chris : https://askubuntu.com/questions/131900/how-do-i-switch-the-command-key-and-control-key-on-a-macbook-pro

Comment: No, I thought there was a hint at a different approach when I saw the xkb mapping, but I sill couldn't get *both* the Fn and Ctrl key to be non-dead at the same time. I can get either to be the Ctrl_L key, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

To swap fn and control on Ubuntu 22.04 you can enter in the terminal:

`echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/module/applespi/parameters/fnremap`

On older ubuntu's or other distributions you might need `hid_apple` instead of `applespi`.

`echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid/parameters/fnremap`

Comment: I don't want to swap them, I want them both to be the same key, both to be the control key and there to be NO "fn" key.  Actually, I want what Karabiner lets me do on macOS, but that's much more complicated to describe.  I have fn there to be only when I hold the escape key down (for 1 second or more), but a press of it is still escape.  Still both fn and ctrl are the control key, so I can't fat finger and miss it.